# Angular: can't import service into Component, but its Module can

Tags: angular

I've got a project with a UserDataService inside of a UserModule. I want to use this UserDataService in another Module's Component. I can import it into EntryModule and list it as a provider, no problem. But in my EntryListComponent, I can't import it. Visual Code is telling me the file doesn't exist, even though I'm 100% sure the path is correct.

Is there any kind of setting that's preventing me from using my UserDataService in a Component found in a different Module?

Here's a snippet of the file tree:

```
src
 |- app
     |- entry
     |    |- entry.module.ts // has UserDataService as provider
     |    |- ..other stuff..
     |    |- entry-list
     |         |- entry-list.component.ts // can't import UserDataService???
     |
     | - user
           |- user.module.ts
           |- user-data.service.ts
           |- ..other stuff..
```

And here's the relevant code in EntryListComponent:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs/Subject';
import { HttpErrorResponse } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Entry } from '../entry.model';
import { EntryDataService } from '../entry-data.service';
//import { UserDataService } from '../../user/user-data.service';
import { distinctUntilChanged, debounceTime, map, filter, debounce } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-entry-list',
  templateUrl: './entry-list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./entry-list.component.css']
})
export class EntryListComponent implements OnInit {

  private _entries : Entry[];

  constructor(private _entryDataService : EntryDataService/*,
  private _userDataService : UserDataService*/) { }

  // ...

}
```

I also noticed that suddenly, changes for EntryListComponent are not tracked by git either... Frustrating. But maybe it's a related issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Should be no reason to import the service into the component. A snapshot of my setup amended to reflect your setup. Hope it helps.

user.module.ts

```
import { UserDataService } from './user/user-data.service';
...
providers: [
  { provide: 'userDataService', useClass: UserDataService }
],
```

app.module.ts

```
...
import { UserModule } from './user/user.module';
```

entry-list.component.ts

```
...
constructor(
    @Inject('userDataService') private userDataService,
) {}
```

Comment: This helped, thanks! It appears the problem was that the EntryListComponent wasn't being tracked or something, in any case git claimed there weren't any changes to be pushed when there were. I resolved this by `git fetch -all` followed by `git reset --hard origin/master`, then I could either import the UserDataService *or* use your method, which appears to be a better practice. For anyone reading this: you'll lose any changes you made since last commit, so commit regularly!

Comment: It is good to import the service into the component to utilize typings. You only need to set the providers in the UserModule and not the other modules, then it should be injected just fine.